# ResourceDictionary and Serious Performance Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have two simple `ResourceDictionary` in my application.

**Converters.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:l="clr-namespace:MyApp" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <l:BitmapToBitmapSourceConverter x:Key="BitmapToBitmapSourceConverter"/>
    <l:ObjectToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ObjectToVisibilityConverter"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Styles.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxBase" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Height="16" Margin="0,2,2,2" Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource BitmapToBitmapSourceConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

When they are merged inside my MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Properties/Converters.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Properties/Styles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Canvas>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=SelectedItem}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxBase}"/>
```

I get an exception when it's time to find `BitmapToBitmapSourceConverter` inside my `Styles.xaml`, because it has been defined inside another `ResourceDictionary`.

Someone suggested me to move my resources from `MainWindow.xaml` to `App.xaml` in order to avoid that kind of exceptions. I did it, and suddenly... drama! I don't get anymore that exception, but my application loading time has become 10 times longer. Sometimes it takes more than 5 seconds to show up on my screen, and normally the `Window` content is plain white for 1 or 2 seconds more.

I tried to run my application from the `exe` itself, I tried to run it in both `Debug` and `Release` mode... nothing. No way to get a good performance after moving my resource files and I can't deliver the application to my customer actually.

Anyone can explain me why and provide a good solution for this?!

Comment: Can you not just reference your other Res. Dict. from your Styles.xaml via `MergedDictionaries` ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx

Comment: Can you show the usage of the dictionaries?

Comment: @Chris W. I'm already using merged ones. I edited my snippets.

Comment: @Marc I added a clearer code.

Comment: @Zarathos: Hmm, I cant see anything wrong... Can you try merging converters.xaml in the style dictionary and then merge styles.xaml only in your window? Maybe it is some lookup issue because styles.xaml doesn't originally 'know' the converter it is using. Just a guess.

Comment: @Zarathos I was referring to within Styles.xaml so elements within it could find elements within Converters.xaml as opposed to both referenced in the `Window.Resources` but I'll try and revisit this issue later if more free time presents itself. :)

Comment: @Marc ok i discovered that the issue concerns the converter, once removed, there is no more slowdown. Why?!

Comment: Can you add a constructor to the converter and see how often it is hit?

Comment: Ok it was a problem in a converter, I wasn't checking for type of the value...